# Wordpress is cut off when linking to pages using /index.php/page-name

Tags: wordpress, permalinks, absolute-path, bitnami

I have posted [this question](http://answers.bitnami.org/questions/4107/wordpress-is-cut-off-when-linking-to-pages-using-indexphppage-name) on bitnami answers as well but I am refining it here. The relevant link is:

I am running the bitnami wordpress stack on my Kubuntu Linux machine. I am linking to pages internal to my site in my content with absolute links like this `/index.php/page-name` and my server is running at `http://127.0.1.1/wordpress/`. The appropriate relative links work correctly but the absolute links do not.

The behaviour I am getting with the absolute links is that the `/wordpress/` path component is truncated when using `/index.php/page-name` and points to `http://127.0.1.1/index.php/page-name` instead of `http://127.0.1.1/wordpress/index.php/page-name`.

I am using the Post name permalink structure and my .htaccess file also has the following rewrite rules:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Every time I click the link I get a 404 error with this message in the apache error log:

`script '/home/nandu/wordpress-3.3.1-1/apache2/htdocs/index.php' not found or unable to stat`

I am not sure why the wordpress part of the URL is getting cut off when my settings in the admin area show both the site url and address url pointing to `http://127.0.1.1/wordpress`.

Furthermore according to the wordpress [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Linking_Posts_Pages_and_Categories) `/index.php/` should point to the site root.

I am at my wits end as far as this problem is concerned. Kindly do let me know if you require any more information.

Thanks in advance.
nav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have succeeded in getting my bitnami wordpress stack to run wordpress on the root url `http://127.0.1.1/` so that the links in my content will work identically to my production system.

Here are the steps I followed modify  to suit your needs:

1. Edit the following lines in `/<INSTALL_DIR>/apache2/conf/httpd.conf`

   from:

   `DocumentRoot "/<INSTALL_DIR>/apache2/htdocs"`

   to

   `DocumentRoot "/<INSTALL_DIR>/apps/wordpress/htdocs"`
2. In the same file, also change the following directive

   from

   `<Directory "/<INSTALL_DIR>/apache2/htdocs">`

   to

   `<Directory "/<INSTALL_DIR>/apps/wordpress/htdocs">`
3. Go to `/<INSTALL_DIR>/apps/wordpress/conf/wordpress.conf` and comment out the following lines by prepending a `#`:

   `Alias /wordpress/ "/<INSTALL_DIR>/apps/wordpress/htdocs/"`

   `Alias /wordpress "/<INSTALL_DIR>/apps/wordpress/htdocs"`
4. In the same file change

   from:

   `RewriteBase /wordpress/`

   to

   `RewriteBase /`
5. In the same file, uncomment the following lines by removing the #:

   `#RewriteEngine On`

   `#RewriteRule ^/$ /wordpress/ [PT]`
6. Restart the bitnami apache server:

   `/<INSTALL_DIR>/ctlscript restart`
7. Edit the following lines in `/<INSTALL_DIR>/apps/wordpress/htdocs/.htaccess`

   from:

   `RewriteBase /wordpress/`

   to

   `RewriteBase /`

   and

   `RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]`

   to

   `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]`
8. Login to PHPMyAdmin at `http://127.0.1.1/phpmyadmin` and go to the wp_options table change `siteurl` value

   from:

   `http://127.0.1.1/wordpress`

   to

   `http://127.0.1.1`
9. After this rename the `index.html` file in the `/<INSTALL_DIR>/apache2/htdocs/` directory to `old-index.html`
10. Restart the bitnami apache server:

    `/<INSTALL_DIR>/ctlscript restart`

Navigating to `http://127.0.1.1/` should show the homepage of the site. There is some documentation on the [bitnami wordpress docs](http://wiki.bitnami.org/Applications/BitNami_Wordpress#How_to_change_the_default_URL.3f) about what needs to be done to change the root url but they seemed incomplete in terms of what I had to do to accomplish this.

Hope that helps someone. :-)
nav

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're trying to write your links via `index.php`.  You should create links that match the permalinks that WordPress itself would produce.  So, instead of `/index.php/page-name`, you would put `/wordpress/page-name`.

Comment: Thank your for your reply. These absolute links work on my production site flawlessly and I wanted to keep the same url structure on my development site. Just to clarify my permalink structure is `http://127.0.1.1:8080/wordpress/sample-post/` and my understanding was that `/index.php/` matches `http://127.0.1.1:8080/wordpress`

Comment: Perhaps you have a different `.htaccess` in production?  As currently written, the one you've posted *won't* map `/index.php/` to `http://127.0.1.1:8080/wordpress`.  Your rules are prefaced with `RewriteBase`, which is a way to say "for all links starting with...".  Then it says to directly pass through a URL ending with `index.php`.  Then it's saying to send any URL that doesn't reference an actual file or directory to `/wordpress/index.php`.  So given all that, you'll need to have at least the leading `/wordpress`...

Comment: Yes my .htaccess file is different on production. If I were to make the .htaccess file on development the same as production and change my siteurl address to just plain `http://127.0.1.1:8080/` that should work am I correct? Or is there another way to change my .htaccess so that index.php maps to `http://127.0.1.1:8080/wordpress`. My knowledge on .htaccess files is very limited I am afraid.

Comment: Whenever possible, have your development environment mirror your production server exactly...that's the best way to avoid mixups later. :)  I would definitely copy down your `.htaccess`, change your siteurl, and then see where you stand.

Comment: Thanks @stevevls I have succeeded in getting my bitnami to act like my production system after much effort and have put up an answer of the steps to follow.